# Typescript:Iterate over list of checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I work on angular 4, I have list of checkbox which on page load will be unchecked.
There is a delete button which will be enabled when any checkbox is checked.

hero.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heros">
    <span>
        <input type='checkbox' name='drama' (click)='selectedHero()' />
    </span>
    <span>hero.name</span>
</div>
<button [class.disabled]='!inEditMode'>Delete</button>
```

hero.component.ts

```
private inEditMode = false;

selectedHero(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByName("drama");
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (elements[i].checked) {
                this.inEditMode = true;
            }
            else {
                this.inEditMode = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error in `.type` and `.checked`.

Error is

```
Property 'type' doesnot exist on type 'HTMLElement
Property 'checked' doesnot exist on type 'HTMLElement.
```

How can I iterate over the checkboxes to see if any on them is checked, and if checked enable the button. And if not checked disabled the button? Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine, but your for loop in typescript sometime works and sometime fails because of for loop.

in your html : `<button [disabled]='!inEditMode'>Delete</button>`

In your typescript:

```
selectedHero() {
   var elements = (<HTMLInputElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName("drama"));
   for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   if (elements[i].type == "checkbox") {
      if (elements[i].checked) {
         console.log("Checked", elements[i].checked);
         this.inEditMode = true;
         break;                      //<== Add this line in your for loop
       }
       else {
         console.log("Unchecked", elements[i].checked);
         this.inEditMode = false;
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

When for loop starts until all elements has to be check you have to break the for loop when atleast one checkbox is checked.

Here is working example:  [Enable Button on mutiple check box selection](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edmbwt)

Hope this will works for you!!!

Comment: i checked your working example and can see same error which I got 

Property 'type' doesnot exist on type 'HTMLElement
Property 'checked' doesnot exist on type 'HTMLElement.

Errors are on .type and .checked

Comment: @Anna Now this might be helpful for you.

Comment: Done. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Selected this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the result of `getElementsByName("drama");`
like this:

```
var elements = (<HTMLInputElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName('drama'));
```

as document.getElementsByName() returns the type `HTMLElement`

Comment: Error is gone, but the button is not getting enabled and disabled correctly. Any leads where I am wrong? So even when the checkbox is clicked the button is disable.

Comment: HTML: `<button id='delBtn'>Delete</button>`
TS, in if part :  `document.getElementById('delBtn').disabled = false;`
in else part do: `document.getElementById('delBtn').disabled = true;`

Comment: also use `break;` in If part.when checking whether any checkbox is checked

Answer (score 0):

Try with .

The problem is that typescript is typesafe. The elements[i] holds the type HTMLElement which does not contain a type property. The subtype HTMLInputElement does however contain the type property.

```
selectedHero(){
var elements = document.getElementsByName("drama");
for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
var element = <HTMLInputElement>elements[i];
if(element.type == "checkbox"){
if(element.checked){
this.inEditMode = true;
}
else{
this.inEditMode = false;
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Error is gone, but the button is not getting enabled and disabled correctly. Any leads where I am wrong? So even when the checkbox is clicked the button is disable.

Answer (score 0):

your elements[i] is a **HTMLElement**, typecast it to **HTMLInputElement**.

Checked property will be there for HTMLInputElement in typescript.

Below should work.

```
for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
if((elements[i] as HTMLInputElement).type == "checkbox"){
if((elements[i] as HTMLInputElement).checked){
  this.inEditMode = true;
}
```

Comment: Error is gone, but the button is not getting enabled and disabled correctly. Any leads where I am wrong? So even when the checkbox is clicked the button is disable.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not wrong.

Try typecasting it with

```
var elements = (<HTMLInputElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName('drama'));
```

alternative try using ngModel, it makes your life easier.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="checkBox.option1" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">Option
<input [(ngModel)]="checkBox.option2" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">Option
```

`<button [disabled]='checkBox.option1 || checkBox.option2'>Delete</button>`

> app.component.ts

```
checkBox:any{};
constructor(){
   checkBox={
       option1:false,
       option2:false
   };
}
```

optionChecked becomes true when checked thus disabling the button

Comment: I tried [(ngModel)] approach, and onclick of single checkbox all the checkbox is getting selected.

Comment: and from 1st approach error is gone, but the button is not getting enabled and disabled correctly. Any leads where I am wrong? So even when the checkbox is clicked the button is disable.

Comment: you have to give it different ngModel for each check box and put it all in the [disabled] attribute of button

Comment: try using the model as `checkbox.option1` `checkbox.option2` and use it in [disabled] attribute. its a neater approach trust me

Comment: my code has a *ngFor loop, so n number of checkbox will be there. So using [(ngModel)]="checkBox.option1" will also get iterated and this will create a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When working with checkboxes, I create an array of checkboxes and in that array, I keep all (in your case id of heroes) checked checkboxes. If array is empty, you disable your button, and if array has at least one member, you enable button. Also when you want to check which checkboxes are checked, you simply itterate through an array of checkboxes.

```
checkarray: any = [];
```

To check is checkbox checked:

```
isChecked(item: any): boolean {
        if (this.checkarray.find(x => x.IDHero == item.IDHero)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

To delete member from array:

```
deletefromArray(array: any, element: any, id: string) {
        let temp: any = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            temp.push(array[i]);
        }
        array.splice(0);
        for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            if (temp[i][id] != element[id]) {
                array.push(temp[i]);
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

To add checked checkboxes to array:

```
checkbox(item: IDK, event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        if (this.checkarray.find(x => x.IDHero == item.IDHero)) {
            this.deleteFromArray(this.checkarray, item, 'IDHero');

            let temp: any = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < this.checkarray.length; i++) {
                temp.push(this.checkarray[i]);
            }
            this.checkarray.splice(0);
            for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                if (temp[i].IDHero != item.IDHero) {
                    this.checkarray.push(temp[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else {          
            this.checkarray.push(item);
        }
    }
    else {      
        if (!this.checkarray.find(x => x.IDHero == item.IDHero)) {
            this.checkarray.splice(0);
            this.checkarray.push(item);
        } else {
            this.checkarray.splice(0);
        }

    }
}
```

I use `CTRL` for multy check.

HTML would be:

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heros" (click)="checkbox(hero,$event)>
<span><input type='checkbox' name='drama' [checked]="isChecked(hero)"/></span>
<span>hero.name</span>
```

```
<button [disabled]='checkarray.length == 0'>Delete</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed post. I tried your code, I get delete button with every checkbox which is wrong. My requirement is I have only 1 delete button and that should enable and disable.

Comment: @Anna Code for delete button is only as explanation. Please place your delete button where ever you want. Delete button doesn't need to be with checkboxes. It can be anywhere on your page. I put it there just to spare space in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add one extra property in Hero model like, IsSelected and bind it with every check-boxes

```js
selectedHero() {

  var data = this.heroes.find((obj: Hero) => obj.IsSelected === true);
  if (data) {
    this.inEditMode = true;
  } else {
    this.inEditMode = false;
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let hero of heros">
  <span>
       <input type='checkbox' value="{{hero.IsSelected}}" [(ngModel)]="hero.IsSelected" name='IsSelected' (change)='selectedHero()'/> />
    </span>
  <span>hero.name</span>
</div>
<button [class.disabled]='!inEditMode'>Delete</button>
```

[stackblitz working demo](https://angular-tour-of-heroes-example-u1cmlh.stackblitz.io/heroes)

Comment: Your approach is good and neat. But I cannot play with model as this is generated by the back-end team so I should not add new property as this might break sometime later.

Comment: You just need to add extra property on client side and it will never affect your server side code.

Comment: Ok, i tried and (obj: Hero) is giving error as "Cannot find name Hero"

Comment: try any instead of Hero: this.heroes.find((obj: any) => obj.IsSelected === true);